# Generic first argument C++ function

Tags: c++, qml

I have a lot of setters.  Is there a generic way to get the first argument of each setter without spelling the name of each different setters argument? For example:

```
void
Class::setSelectedEntryIndex(int newSelectedEntryIndex) {
    m_log(ExEr) << "first arg: " << newSelectedEntryIndex << std::endl;
    m_selectedEntryIndex = newSelectedEntryIndex;
    emit selectedEntryIndexChanged();
}

replaced with:

void
Class::setSelectedEntryIndex(int newSelectedEntryIndex) {
    m_log(ExEr) << "first arg: " << this->firstArg << std::endl;   // Change here
    m_selectedEntryIndex = newSelectedEntryIndex;
    emit selectedEntryIndexChanged();
}
```

?

Comment: No. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: i want to log, copy and paste this log every function with 1 arg to print it out so i don't have to spell the names for each one for each log

Comment: Call the argument `arg1` and print `arg1`.  It'll have different types in different functions, but the name is always the same.  Example: `void Class::setSelectedEntryIndex(int arg1) { m_log(ExEr) << "first arg: " << arg1 << std::endl; m_selectedEntryIndex = arg1; emit selectedEntryIndexChanged(); }`

Comment: Write a template function that, in turn, writes the log information. Then call it from the setters.

Comment: just use the same name for each setters argument. It's only a dummy name, so the actual name doesn't matter (as long as it doesn't clash with any other name in the current scope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the way you propose. You *could* change the parameter-list into an `std::tuple` but since you're dealing with setters I assume your parameter-list have one parameter each.

Your best shot to automate (what I think you want to do) is to simply name all parameters the same in your function definition. You can still give them descriptive names in the declaration, since C++ doesn't care about that, anyway.

#### .h

```
class MyClass {
  void setTemperature(int newTemperature);
  // or
  void setTemperature(int); // <- people sometimes find this less self-documentative
};
```

#### .cpp

```
void MyClass::setTemperature(int param1) {
  m_log(ExEr) << "first arg: **" << param1 << std::endl;
  /* ... */
}
```